# Re-run Cypress tests in GUI when webpack-dev-server causes page reload

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, cypress

I'm using webpack-dev-server and the Cypress GUI for a development workflow and I'd like for Cypress to automatically re-run/restart tests when the page reloads as triggered by WDS auto-reload.

What happens now is that I see WDS cause the page to reload, but the Cypress session just stays where it left off.

I can't seem to find a way to make this happen. I'm not seeing any public (or private, for that matter) way to trigger Cypress to re-run the currently selected test.

Comment: have you gotten this to working yet?

Comment: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/456 is still open at time of writing; any official solution will be mentioned there.

Answer (score 4):

#### UPDATE: Now there's an NPM package for this

[cypress-hmr-restarter](https://github.com/svish/cypress-hmr-restarter#readme) - it listens to the websocket that webpack-dev-server uses to reload the page

```sh
npm install --save-dev cypress-hmr-restarter
```

in `cypress/support/index.js`:

```js
// cypress/support/index.js
import 'cypress-hmr-restarter'
```

see https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/456#issuecomment-566499738

#### Older hacky solution:

You can add the following to `cypress/support/index.js` (or at the top of a spec file):

```js
Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win)=>{
  const _consoleInfo = win.console.info
  win.console.info = function () {
    if (arguments[0].includes('App updated.')) {
      cy.$$('.restart', top.document).click()
    }
    return _consoleInfo.apply(win.console, arguments)
  }
})
```

This will work as long as you have `webpack-dev-server` info being printed to the console (there are no other hooks into the webpack reloading behavior I could find)

The `$('.restart').click()` is a hilariously simple way to trigger a test re-run

Alternatively, you could try this plugin which sets up its own watchers on your source files, and re-runs your tests when changes are detected: https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-watch-and-reload

Answer (score 0):

@kuceb Thanks for the update regarding cypress-hmr-restarter!

For my Angular 14 project I had to set (in `cypress.json`):

```
"hmrUrl": "ws://localhost:4200/ng-cli-ws"
```

Works like a charm!